# MySQL delete duplicate records but keep more than one (ex. 5)

Tags: mysql

I have a table with several duplicated records and  I would like to delete some of them based on a specific number (ex. 3 or 5 pr 10 duplicated records). How can  I implement that in the MySQL ?

Example of records:

```
ID           TEXT
1000         HELLO JOHN
1001         HELLO JOHN
1002         HELLO JOHN
1003         HELLO JOHN      
1004         HELLO JOHN
1005         HELLO JOHN
1006         HELLO JOHN
1007         HELLO JOHN
1008         HELLO JOHN
1009         HELLO JOHN
ETC...
```

For me does not import if I delete in ascending or descending mode. I just want to delete the records in a controled way (ex. 3 records, 5 records, 10 records, etc)

I expect to have the following output for example (in ascending mode)

```
ID           TEXT
1000         HELLO JOHN
1001         HELLO JOHN
1002         HELLO JOHN
1003         HELLO JOHN
1004         HELLO JOHN
```

Comment: How do you determine which to keep?  Is it those with the _lowest_ 3, 5, or 10, ID's or by some other method?

Comment: what is your MySQL version?

Comment: In your example that is for `N = 5`, isnt?

Comment: Just to note that statements like "doesn't matter which are retained" are often indicative of poor design. It *should* matter!

Comment: like @Strawberry saids also iám not sure want your asking here.. Do you want to give a number like 3 if there are more duplicates the "first"/"last" 3 records should be keeped and the rest deleted? There should be some kind of order..

Comment: For me it is not important to control what ids will stay, For my specific problem  I just need to remove the excedent records. In the example I removed the excedent and just remained  N= 5, but could be N= 3, 4, 6, etc....

Comment: in that case make a temporary table  and use `INSERT INTO temp SELECT ... FROM your_table WHERE TEXT = 'text' ORDER BY ID RAND() LIMIT 5` and truncate your_table and copy the temporary data in your_table. Or the better options a deliverd table/co-related queries like in some answers posted.

Comment: Hi @raymond nijland  ! It is not a question of poor design. Imagine several duplicated SNMP alarms being loaded in a database. It is quite similar etc...

Comment: *" It is not a question of poor design"* where did i say it was a bad design? but i agree with @Strawberry the order should matter.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well, to be fair, I said it could be indicative of poor design, and you seemed to agree with me!

Comment: MAy be I was not clear enough - I am sorry for that  - but what matters for me in the query is to count the field TEXT. I want to retain 5 (five) repetitions - for example - of the same TEXT field.
The IDs are not complete sequential (they can sparse in hundres or thousands of values for each repetitive TEXT).
Example:

1000  HELLO JOHN
1001  HELLO JOHN
1002  HELLO JOHN
1003  HELLO JOHN
1004  HELLO JOHN
1012  HELLO MARY
1013  HELLO MARY
1014  HELLO MARY
1015  HELLO MARY
1016  HELLO MARY
1221  HELLO JACK
1222  HELLO JACK
1223  HELLO JACK
1224  HELLO JACK
1225  HELLO JACK

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
DELETE t_n
FROM 
       table_name AS t_n
   JOIN
       ( SELECT id 
         FROM table_name
         WHERE text='HELLO JOHN'
         ORDER BY id       
           LIMIT 5
       ) AS lim
     ON t_n.id > lim.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have multiple texts duplicate not just `HELLO JOHN`.

So you use session variable to emulate `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION ...`

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17129/1)**

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE `ID` NOT IN ( 
                    SELECT `ID`
                    FROM (
                            SELECT `ID`,        
                                   @rn:= if (@text = `TEXT`, 
                                             @rn+1, 
                                             if(@text := `TEXT`,1,1)
                                            ) as rn       
                            FROM Table1
                            CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0 , @text := '') as vars
                            ORDER BY `ID` 
                          ) as t
                    WHERE rn <=5                        
                  );
```

Comment: What I really need is something like:

Comment: Check My edit. I add the option to work even with multiple texts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple query to do this is.

```
DELETE FROM Table1 
WHERE ID NOT IN(
  SELECT 
   a.ID
  FROM (
    SELECT 
     ID 
    FROM 
     Table1
    ORDER BY 
     Table1.ID ASC
    LIMIT 5
  ) AS a
)
```

see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/181179/1)

as you can't do

```
DELETE FROM Table1 
WHERE ID NOT IN(
    SELECT 
     ID 
    FROM 
     Table1
    ORDER BY 
     Table1.ID ASC
    LIMIT 5
)
```

Because it errors

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME
>   subquery'

see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/047c72/1)